# Cross verify test automation results between two different clients running parallely

Tags: multithreading, automated-tests, ui-automation

So I have a requirement where I need to run two clients parallely and tasks are performed on both the clients simultaneously. For the test automation framework, I'm currently controlling the threads using fine grained parallelism, where I'm creating two threads and then instantiating the two clients and performing the tasks. My question is, is there a way in any of the frameworks where the test steps themselves could be parallelized? for example in Cucumber or robot.

Comment: If you are looking to parallelize specific steps, Behave (python) supports   `context.execute_steps()`. This can be called in a more generic step. In case your are interested, I could expand it to an answer.

Comment: hey, yes I'm interested. It would be great if you can expand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, not out of the box. As to Cucumber solutions, Behave allows you to [calli steps from other steps](http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#calling-steps-from-other-steps), thus

> steps themselves could be parallelized

This however could be achieved in your framework via [DSL](http://www.marcusoft.net/2013/04/PushTheHowDown.html), since the steps themselves are simple glue code. Your top most layer (Gherkin) doesn't need to understand how this is working, only that it should be specified (ideally with meta data e.g. `@tags`). Here is a [Github repo with parallel-runner](https://github.com/hugeinc/behave-parallel) on scenario level. You could find some ideas and code to reuse.